# Activity is leaking a window

Tags: android

I am new to Android technology, and I am creating a practice app. I have created a mail sending class that is used in two Activities. In one Activity it is working fine, but in the other it is not working -- there is an error in the logcat and I am unable to find what is causing it. Here is the error log:

```
03-19 12:11:23.773: E/WindowManager(891): Activity com.example.mytest.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d0de70 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-97,92} that was originally added here
03-19 12:11:23.773: E/WindowManager(891): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.mytest.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d0de70 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-97,92} that was originally added here
03-19 12:11:23.773: E/WindowManager(891):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
03-19 12:11:23.773: E/WindowManager(891):   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
03-19 12:11:23.773: E/WindowManager(891):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
03-19 12:11:23.773: E/WindowManager(891):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
03-19 12:11:23.773: E/WindowManager(891):   at com.example.mytest.MainActivity$CountDownTask.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:289)
03-19 12:11:23.773: E/WindowManager(891):   at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
03-19 12:11:23.773: E/WindowManager(891):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
03-19 12:11:23.773: E/WindowManager(891):   at com.example.mytest.MainActivity.CallLogsBackup(MainActivity.java:91)
03-19 12:11:23.773: E/WindowManager(891):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 12:11:23.773: E/WindowManager(891):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-19 12:11:23.773: E/WindowManager(891):   at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3592)
03-19 12:11:23.773: E/WindowManager(891):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
03-19 12:11:23.773: E/WindowManager(891):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
03-19 12:11:23.773: E/WindowManager(891):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-19 12:11:23.773: E/WindowManager(891):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-19 12:11:23.773: E/WindowManager(891):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-19 12:11:23.773: E/WindowManager(891):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-19 12:11:23.773: E/WindowManager(891):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 12:11:23.773: E/WindowManager(891):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-19 12:11:23.773: E/WindowManager(891):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-19 12:11:23.773: E/WindowManager(891):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-19 12:11:23.773: E/WindowManager(891):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It should be somewhere in your code. But no one can help till we see some of it. ;-)

Comment: Your code and logcat stack trace, where is it?

Comment: Sorry guys i have edit my post and here is the error log

Comment: How about this:MainActivity$CountDownTask.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:289)

Comment: when looking at logcat search first for your namespace, in this case com.example.mytest, this way you have an hint on what's making android angry

Comment: Without knowing what you're doing it's hard to be certain, but I've received this in the log when I forgot to correctly `dismiss()` a `Dialog` after `finish()`ing an `Activity`

Comment: @jprofitt: I have dismiss() it in onPostExecute()

Comment: we can't say something unless you don't share your codes

Comment: Thanks guys i have done it.............